# Problem with using spacy.matcher.matcher.Matcher.add() method - Using Spacy 2.2. version

Tags: python, addition, spacy, matcher

I am getting an error when trying to use spacy matcher:

ValueError: [E171] Matcher.add received invalid on_match callback argument: expected callable or None, but got: <class 'list'>

I am using spacy version 2.2.0

I was expecting extraction of President names as per the pattern defined for the matcher.

Comment: match code is     # pattern
    pattern = [{'LOWER':'president'},
              {'POS':'ADP','OP':'?'},
              {'POS':'PROPN'}]
                
    # Matcher class object 
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab) 
    matcher.add("names",[pattern])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.